# Cannot unload HKU registry hive

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I've got a weird problem. Using Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.19042.804), I am an administrator (logged in as Administrator) on a machine. Using regedit, I navigate to the HKEY_USERS hive, click on File, Load Hive and load the following: C:\Users\TestAccount\NTUSER.DAT and I name this Test

The Test hive correctly appears under HKEY_USERS. I can see, edit, add and delete anything in this hive.

When I click on Test and then click on File, Unload Hive, I get an error message saying: Cannot Unload Test. Access is denied.

What am I doing wrong?? This behaviour persists even if I run regedit 'as admin'. The only way to unload the hive currently is to reboot.